# Onclick not working in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating html in javascript file, and i am trying to click on  tag, i have added editNote() in  tag, and i have called it out side, but my problem is , editNote() function can't execute. So can you tell me how to execute this function ?

```
html += '<a onclick="editNote(' + note.id + ', ' + userId + ')" style="cursor:pointer"><i style="color:blue" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x"></i></a>';
```

**Function**

```
function editNote(noteId, userId) {
    alert(noteId);
}
```

Comment: Please post complete in which you are writing this line.

Comment: Have you javascript errors in your console?

Comment: @C0dekid I don't think this is the problem since that worked for me without the href attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me with slight modifications. Please consider code below

```js
var note = {id: 5},
    userId = 56;

html = '<a onclick="editNote(' + note.id + ', ' + userId + ')" style="cursor:pointer;" href="#">button</a>';

document.write(html);

function editNote(noteId, userId) {
    alert(noteId);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script...
I hope this help's

```
<div id="click">your code here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var noteId = 1;
    var userId = 2;

    var html = '<a onclick="editNote('+noteId+','+userId+')" style="cursor:pointer"><i style="color:blue" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x">CLICK ME</i></a>';

    document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = html;

    function editNote(noteId, userId) {
        alert(noteId);
        alert(userId);
    }
</script>
```